# Less number of levels for a categorical variable in decision tree output

Tags: r, machine-learning, tree

I am presently fitting a model using decision tree and the data set contains both numeric and categorical variables. One of the variable is a categorical variable A having 3 levels: Good, Bad and Medium. Now, when I fit the model using 'tree' package, it gave the tree output with A as my root node but with only 2 levels and the significant level, Good is not included in the tree. To experiment, I have increased the Good values in the input dataset to more than 200 in a dataset of 400 but still it did not included it in the tree output. Why is that so?. And what to do force it to include Good in the tree?.

Comment: can you share some code please so we can understand the problem

Comment: #1)Data setup
attach(Carseats) #ISLR package
High=ifelse(Sales<=8,"No","Yes")
Carseats=data.frame(Carseats,High)
                                                                                                       
   #2)Creating Classification Tree
class.tree=tree(High~.-Sales,data=Carseats)
names(class.tree)
summary(class.tree)
plot(class.tree)
text(class.tree,pretty=0)

Comment: Add the code to the body of the question, not the comments.